# How do I show that an element of a topological space lies in the closure of a subset of a topological space?

Tags: general-topology

Consider the vector space of functions $X = \{ f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \}$ with the topology $\tau$ generated by a subbasis given by $S_{n,u,v} = \{f \in X | u < f(n) < v\}$. Let $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto 1$ be the constant function.

I need to prove that $g$ belongs to the closure of $A = \{ f \in X | f(x) \neq 0$ for finitely many x $\}$.

I know by definition, $g \in \bar{A} \Leftrightarrow \forall$ neighbourhood $O$ of $g : O \cap A \neq \emptyset$. So, I should start by choosing a open neighbourhood around $g$ and then show that the intersection is not empty. But this has not lead me anywhere.

I have considered another approach using the fact that $g \in \bar{A}$ if and only if $g$ is a limit pt. of $A$. In the notes, that it am using, it has a statement that says, A sequence of functions $\{f_n(x)\}$ in $X$ converges pointwise in $X$ if and only if it converges in $(X,\tau)$. But I am unsure if I can actually use this idea.

I suppose I could consider X with the product topology and apply the above theorem but I am not sure.

I am self studying topology, so any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What are the open neighbourhoods of $g$? Maybe it helps if you ponder a little which - hopefully familiar - topology $\tau$ is.

Comment: It seems to me $\tau$ is the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$. But I have managed to confuse myself throughly, and seem to be getting no where.

Comment: No, $\tau$ is a topology on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh! So $\tau$ is the product topology on $X$.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The rest should now not be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Let $U$ be any basic neighbourhood of $g$. This means that it is a finite intersection of subbasic elements, so $U = \cap_{j=1}^m S_{n_j,u_j,v_j}$. So basically this neighbourhood determines a range for the values at finitely many points $n_1,\dots,n_m$. And we know that the function that is $1$ everywhere obeys these ranges at these points.

Now let $f$ be the function that is $1$ at all points $n_j$, $j=1,\ldots,m$ and $0$ everywhere else. By construction, $f \in A$ and also $f \in U$, as $F$ is one, just like $g$ at all the contraint points $n_j$, so obeys the contraints there.